# How can I go specific page on FlowDocumentReader?

Tags: wpf, flowdocumentreader

How can I go specific page on FlowDocumentReader?
Of course, i'm using pages mode on FlowDocumentReader.

I heard that FlowDocumentPageViewer has GoToPage( ) method. so it is easier to use FlowDocumentPageViewer instead of FlowDocumentReader.

However, I hope to use Page Mode & Scroll Mode.
I hope to use GoToPage function at only Page Mode on FlowDocumentReader.

Can I get the solution - How can I go specific page on FlowDocumentReader?
( or I want to know how can I get FlowDocumentPageViewer from FlowDocumentReader. I think FlowDocumentReader has 3 modes ( like FlowDocumentPageViewer, scrollviewer...). So may it possible to convert.

Can I know the ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The both of things which you want is impossible.
However, you can create a new class by extending from FlowDocumentReader.

You can see the source code of FlowDocumentReader - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/FlowDocumentReader.cs,ccac5a02d450af41.

So, try to create what you want.